# Custom model fields and form fields in reusable Django app: naming convention

Tags: django

I'm writing a reusable Django app that provides both custom model fields and custom form fields. I was thinking to place one of the two pieces in a file called `fields.py` but, clearly, I cannot place both the model and form fields in the same file.

My question is: **is there any naming convention or recommended best practice for naming custom model fields and custom form fields in a reusable app?**

I was thinking of copying the structure of Django, but the fields file are both in separate modules (`django.db.model.fields` and `django.forms.fields`) while my form and model fields live in the same module (the app).

The documentation says nothing about naming conventions in this case: it simply explains how to code the fields, not where the code should be (that is left to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Django places model fields in `django.db.model.fields` and form fields in `django.forms.fields`, for the purposes of most Django developers, this is just an internal implementation detail.

Model and form fields are accessed directly through the `models` and `forms` modules:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Question(models.Model):
    question_test = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

For a simple app, could just place model and form place fields in `models.py` and `forms.py`, respectively. This way, the interface to your app will match that of Django.

For a more complex app, you can create a hierarchy with `db/fields.py` and `forms/fields.py`. But if you're trying to follow Django's interface closely, you would want the fields to still be accessible through `models` or `forms` modules. To achieve that, you would want to import the contents of the relevant `fields.py` file into `db/models.py` or `forms/__init__.py` with something like:

```
from .fields import *
```

Hope this helps.